# ANTLR antlrWorks error messages are not displayed to the output console

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

When enter the following input with an error at the third line:

```
SELECT entity_one, entity_two FROM myTable;
first_table, extra_table as estable, tineda as cam;
asteroid tenga, tenta as myName, new_eNoal as coble
```

I debugged it with antlrWorks and found that the error message corresponding to the third line gets shown on the debugger output window:

output/__Test___input.txt line 3:8 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input ' '
output/__Test___input.txt line 3:9 missing END_COMMAND at 'tenga'

but when I run the application by itself these error messages are not being displayed at the console.

The error messages get displayed on the console whenever the error is on the first line like:

```
asteroid tenga, tenta as myName, new_eNoal as coble
SELECT entity_one, entity_two FROM myTable;
first_table, extra_table as estable, tineda as cam;
```

console output:

inputSql.rst line 1:8 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input ' '
inputSql.rst line 1:9 missing END_COMMAND at 'tenga'

How could I have them displayed on the console too when the errors are not located at the 1st line?

---

```
                         UserRequest.g
```

---

```
grammar UserRequest;

tokens{
    COMMA = ',' ;       
    WS = ' ' ;  
    END_COMMAND = ';' ;
}

@header {
package com.linktechnology.input;
}

@lexer::header {
package com.linktechnology.input;
}

@members{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            UserRequestLexer lex = new UserRequestLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]));
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);

            UserRequestParser parser = new UserRequestParser(tokens);

            try {
                parser.request();
            } catch (RecognitionException e)  {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

process :   request* EOF  ; 

 request    :   (sqlsentence | create) END_COMMAND ;

sqlsentence :   SELECT fields tableName ; 

fields  :   tableName (COMMA tableName)*  FROM ;                  

create  :   tableName (COMMA tableName)+ ;

tableName   :   WS* NAME (ALIAS NAME)? ;        


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

NAME    :   LETTER ( LETTER |DIGIT | '-' | '_' )* ;

fragment LETTER: LOWER | UPPER;

fragment LOWER:  'a'..'z';

fragment UPPER: 'A'..'Z';

fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';    

SELECT  :    ('SELECT ' |'select ' ) ;

FROM    :   (' FROM '|' from ') ;

ALIAS   :   ( ' AS ' |' as ' )  ;

WHITESPACE : (  '\r' | '\n' | '\t' | WS | '\u000C' )+   { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your `main` method, you invoke `parser.request()` while when debugging, you choose the `process` rule as the starting point. And since `request` consumes a single `(sqlsentence | create) END_COMMAND` from your input, it produces no error.

Change the `main` method into:

```java
@members{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UserRequestLexer lex = new UserRequestLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);

        UserRequestParser parser = new UserRequestParser(tokens);

        try {
            parser.process();
        } catch (RecognitionException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and you'll see the same errors on the console since `process` forces the parser to consume the entire input, all the way to `EOF`.

Comment: It's running smoothly now.  Thanks, Bart!